# É correto usar o termo mensageria para envio de mensagens dentro de um mesmo sistema?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, linguagem

Estou em dúvida se o termo "mensageria" pode ser usado em troca de mensagens entre usuários de um único sistema, pois encontrei algumas referências que dizem que o termo pode ser usado apenas quando a comunicação é entre sistemas diferentes.

Comment: Como que "sistema" está definido nesse caso - softwares, máquina, rede, ..? Numa rápida pesquisa encontro o termo definido apenas para comunicações entre máquinas diferentes — mas quando não se exclui a possibilidade explicitamente, em princípio se pode considerar o caso particular das duas máquinas serem a mesma: se aplicável aos "sistemas", então a resposta é "sim". Mas não seria a pergunta técnica demais? Pode ser difícil distinguir entre o "significado" e a "definição técnica" de um termo, mas talvez a pergunta possa caber melhor no [PT StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Lissandra é pena não ter incluido um referência ao artigo que pretende definir o uso rigoroso do termo. O pt.so aceita perguntas para esclarecimento de termos técnicos mas no Stack Overflow este tipo de pergunta já não é aceite hoje em dia como sendo off-topic. De qualquer maneira achei a pergunta geral o suficiente para responder aqui (embora seja da informática é comum aceitarmos perguntas sobre termos técnicos das mais diversas áreas no pt.se)

Comment: @bad_coder Sua resposta bem pesquisada e o fato da pergunta não ser on topic no SO em português me convencem de que a pergunta cabe mesmo bem aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisei no Google e a maioria das ocorrências (as primeiras 100 páginas) do termo "mensageria" são claramente no âmbito tecnológico. Quer isto dizer que **é um termo técnico transversal aos [sistemas distribuídos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_processamento_distribu%C3%ADdo), [paralelos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_concorrente) ou [concorrentes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_paralela) que refere especificamente [message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing)** (usando como língua de referência o inglês).

**No português europeu o substantivo "mensageria" não é usado, pode dizer-se "trocas de mensagens"** (veja por exemplo as palavras chave nesta tese de mestrado ["Uma linguagem de protocolos para descrever sistemas distribuídos tolerantes a falhas", Universidade de Lisboa, 2014](https://repositorio.ul.pt/handle/10451/15436)) e pode comparar com esta tese de doutoramento do Brasil ["UMA ARQUITETURA DE SOFTWARE PARA SISTEMAS ESPAÇO-TEMPORAIS BASEADOS NA WEB...", São Paulo, 2007.](https://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/3/3141/tde-01082007-182328/publico/TeseLuizCarlosVersaoRevisada.pdf) que contém o termo "mensageria".)

Vale a pena notar que em tradução directa do inglês "message passing" é mais próximo usar a expressão "trocas de mensagens" (entre sistemas) do que usar o substantivo "messageria". **Note-se que o substantivo "mensageria" só com uma palavra aproxima-se bastante de "messaging" sendo este último também frequentemente usado com os sentidos de "texting" ou "instant messaging"**, ou seja "bater um papo" (por meio electrónico) ou "trocar mensages" (com os amigos)... Fico com a nítida sensação que o termo "message passing" também é preferido em inglês podendo "messaging" ser usado no mesmo contexto mas geralmente só depois de ter sido usado o termo com duas palavras.

> Estou em dúvida se o termo "mensageria" pode ser usado em troca de mensagens entre usuários de um único sistema

O termo é usado no Google dessa maneira **quando a interação entre os utilizadores é entendida no sentido técnico de uma acção com trocas de mensages entre o sistema**, veja a [definição de mensageria nesta enciclopédia de finanças](https://enfin.com.br/termo/mensageria-iyxu3w3o). (Não é no simples sentido de utilizador A mandou mensagem ao B por telemóvel/celular ou rede social - penso ser nesse sentido que o uso de "mensageria" deve ser evitado como refere na pergunta, uso na óptica do utilizador e não do sistema.)

> É correto usar o termo mensageria para envio de mensagens dentro de um mesmo sistema?

A pergunta parece procurar definir com rigor o uso de "message passing" em função da arquitectura do sistema. O problema é que o termo "trocas de mensages" (ou "mensageria") refere um conceito de comunicação no sentido mais abstracto e geral, pode ser no interior de um sistema ou entre sistemas conforme definirmos sistema.

Um exemplo clássico seriam as filas de mensagens [(message queue) entre threads POSIX](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html), encontrei este exemplo na documentação da linguagem Rust que é intitulado precisamente [Using Message Passing to Transfer Data Between Threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-02-message-passing.html) **(traduzido: "Usando trocas de mensagens para transferência de dados entre threads")**. Acho que este último artigo serve de exemplo paradigmático em como a "mensageria" pode ocorrer dentro de um mesmo sistema.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133582/discussion-on-answer-by-bad-coder-e-correto-usar-o-termo-mensageria-para-envio-d).